# PC Keyboard with Mac: Alt-Tab + other basics?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a macbook pro and a keyboard meant for a PC.  I want to remap some keys and, after googling around, found this:

[Simulate PC keyboard on Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/481137/simulate-pc-keyboard-on-mac)

I just want a few basics:

copy paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

alt-tab to switch between applications (this is normally command tab on a mac)

command-option to switch between tabs on chrome

I've looked through Karabiner / KeyRemap4MacBook but can't seem to sort it out.  Any advice on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

bclayman

Comment: Not what you're asking, but as Control has a different meaning on a Mac, and as you might be using your built-in keyboard too, I'd get used to the order and meaning on a Mac keyboard. So: I'd map the PC's Ctrl, Windows, Alt to the Mac's Ctrl, Option, Command. If you want that, see [How to re-map command and option keys on Mac OS X with a PC-keyboard?](http://superuser.com/questions/80976/how-to-re-map-command-and-option-keys-on-mac-os-x-with-a-pc-keyboard/81843#81843)

Answer (score 8):

After 5 years of asking this question, today i have faced same issue.

so I decided to google the solution and I haven't found an answer to your question.

I kept searching until i got the solution, so I decided to get back to you and tell you what I have found out, is was too simple.

STEPS:

1. Connect the Windows PC keyboard to the Mac as usual, either by USB
   or Bluetooth
2. Pull down the  Apple menu and choose “System Preferences”
3. Click on “Keyboard”
4. Choose the “Keyboard” tab and then click on the “Modifier Keys”
   button in the lower right corner of the preference panel
5. Choose the PC keyboard from the “Select Keyboard” dropdown menu at
   the top of the Modifier keys screen to insure you are modifying the
   proper keyboard connected to the Mac
6. Click the dropdown next to “OPTION Key” and select “Command”
7. Click the dropdown next to “COMMAND Key” and select “Option”

Cite : https://osxdaily.com/2018/01/31/use-windows-pc-keyboard-mac-remap-option-command-keys/

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Comment: How would anyone figure that out on their own? This worked for me as well. Thank you.

Comment: This works but the alt + tab loses it default behavior, which is the same on windows and mac

Comment: you are genius men!

Comment: This works! Mac Pro 19' Ventura 13.5 with Corsair STRAFE RGB MK2

Comment: You deserve a big thumbs up.... Thank you@Rashed Alansari

Answer (score -1):

Well done.  Remapping the two keys via system preferences, keybboard, keyboard, modifier keys is the way to make a PC Keyboard behave like a Mac Keyboard.   I just bought a PC keyboard for my Mac and was very frustrated that none of the possible key combinations (CTRL-Tab, Windows key-Tab, and Alt-Tab) would bring up the oblong picture of all the running programs.  Simply swapping keys Command and Option got things back the way they were with a Mac keyboard.  Now to flip programs I hit Alt-Tab, bearing in mind that the "Alt" is located where the "Command" key is on the Mac keyboard, and vice versa.  The old copy and paste key-combinations of CTRL-C and CTRL-V, are now in their usual places, even if I am in fact hitting Alt-C and Alt-V.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).